# How to return rich messages in custom events in Dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I found the following code online and is trying to get it to work with my bot project (learning how to code and building a bot using express.js, without firebase).

I am using it to get json from 3rd party sites and reply the information in Dialogflow bot.  It can collect the json key, value (data:{}) and reply in events by using event name (name: 'pic-found'). It will reply in the text response (using this set response: #pic-found.content), but only in text.

Is there a way to get it to reply the json data as rich messages (eg. cards, carousel, etc. if the json data has images, multiple items, etc.)?

```
'use strict'

    let axios = require('axios')

    const handler = (interaction) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Check for parameters
        if (!interaction.parameters.hasOwnProperty('tags')) {
          reject(new Error('missing symbol parameter'))
        }

        let tags = interaction.parameters['tags']

        // Fetch the info using rest api
        axios
          .get(`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${tags}`)
          .then(axiosResponse => {
            // Retrieve the info from the response object
            let posts = axiosResponse.data

            // Check if the API returned an error
            if (posts.Response && posts.Response === 'Error') {
              // The API returned an error
              // So build the response object to trigger the failure intent
              interaction.response.followupEvent = {
                name: 'pic-not-found',
                data: {}
              }
            } else {
              // The posts have been successfully retrieved
              // So build the response object to trigger the success intent
              interaction.response.followupEvent = {
                name: 'pic-found',
                data: {
                        title: posts.title.rendered
                        content: posts.content.rendered
                      }
              }
            }

            // Resolve the Promise to say that the handler performed the action without any error
            resolve()
          })
          .catch(e => {
            // An error occured during the request to the API
            // Reject the Promise to say that an error occured while the handler was performing the action
            reject(e)
          })
      })
    }

    module.exports = handler
```